# Nested values are not able to be evaluated

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm using helm v 3.7.0 and I have a parent chart with a few subcharts as dependancies.
One of the subcharts has a virtual service defined as per below.

Subchart Values.yaml:

```
ingress:
  enabled: true
  host: "hostname.local"
  annotations: {}
  tls: []
```

Subchart virtual.service.yaml:

```
{{- if .Values.ingress.enabled -}}
apiVersion: types.kubefed.io/v1beta1
kind: FederatedVirtualService
metadata:
  name: {{ template "product.fullname" . }}-web-vservice
spec:
  placement:
    clusterSelector: {}
  template:
    spec:
      gateways:
      - {{ template "product.fullname" . }}-web-gateway
      hosts:
      - {{ .Values.ingress.host }}
      http:
      # Website
      - match:
        - uri:
            prefix: /
        route:
        - destination:
            host: {{ template "product.fullname" . }}-web
            port:
              number: 80
{{- end }}
```

When I run:

```
helm template . --debug
```

It errors out with:

```
Error: template: virtual.service.yaml:1:14: executing "virtual.service.yaml" at <.Values.ingress.enabled>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.enabled
```

If I move the enabled boolean outside of ingress and update the if statement it works.
i.e.
new values:

```
ingressEnabled: true
ingress:
  host: "hostname.local"
  annotations: {}
  tls: []
```

new virtual service:

```
{{- if .Values.ingressEnabled -}}
apiVersion: types.kubefed.io/v1beta1
kind: FederatedVirtualService
```

The problem is that this is happening all over the place with lots of different values but only where they are nested and I cannot make all values flat.

I have virtual services being specified in exactly the same way in other projects and they work perfectly. I don't believe the issue is with how I'm defining this (unless anyone can correct me?) so I think something else is preventing helm from being able to read nested values but I don't know where to look to investigate this odd behaviour.

What would make helm unable to read nested values?

Comment: Not sure if this is significant, but i think the default values.yaml is lower case. Have you tried to either make the filename start with a lower case letter or pass the values  file explicitly with with `-f`?

Comment: I knew it would be something stupid, that was it. thanks! Never occurred to me it could be that as it could read some values.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment above, I see you were able to overcome the issue and I want to add the answer to the question for other to find.

The default `values.yaml` file is lower case (even though we use `.Values` in the template).

What you can do is either:

- make the filename start with a lowercase letter or
- pass the values file explicitly with with `-f` option

Comment: What would be useful to know is what is it about the file name that stops only nested values being accessible. I could make sense of it if it wasn't able to read\find the file but to be able to read some values but not others leaves more questions.